# Coherence for biadjunctions

Tags: ct.category-theory, 2-categories

There are many ways to give a definition of a biadjunction. For instance, one may say that a pseudofunctor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is left biadjoint to $G:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ if there are pseudo-natural transformations $\eta:Id_{\mathcal{C}}\rightarrow GF$ and $\epsilon:FG\rightarrow Id_{\mathcal{D}}$ satisfying the triangle identities up to invertible modifications.

Now, there is also a coherent version of the latter definition (see [Gurski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0979)), where the modifications witnessing the triangle identites satisfy the swallowtail equations. The ncatlab entry for biadjunctions (and my intuition) makes me believe that every biadjunction can be made coherent, but I haven't been able to find a reference in the litterature. Does anybody know where to find one?

Comment: Did you check out the references cited on the nLab?

Comment: They prove similar results, but as far as I understand not exactly this result. The closest is Pstragowski's result concerning the coherence of duals in monoidal bicatgories. I'm unsure whether people would say it's the reference I'm asking for or not.

Comment: I agree, it's unfortunate that none of the references are *stated* as being about biadjunctions between bicategories.  But they all contain the essential calculations involved in such a proof.